# Pasting text into Excel without splitting on spaces (or other delimiter)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I recently used the Text to Columns feature in Excel to split a column of data into multiple columns based on the space character.  Now when I paste text into Excel it automatically splits it into multiple columns without using the Text to Columns feature.  Is there a way to revert this functionality back to normal?

Comment: mine is splitting url's on the colon... in every spreadsheet I use!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This seemed to work, but is a bit involved.

1. Enter data into a cell.
2. Select the Text to Columns feature.
3. Make sure Delimited is selected and choose Next.
4. Uncheck the check next to Space (or the delimiter you want to disable)
5. Click Finish.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer as the solution @leigh-riffel. It helps the community.

Comment: this worked. so it appears the last text-to-columns operation is used for all future pasting.

Comment: It's used for all future pasting in any workbook, and also set by default whenever you open a text file.

Comment: argh. obvious (in hindsight) - thanks that's a great timesaver

Comment: Sad UX!!.. They should have added an "Auto Split" option/checkbox button right next to the Split Text to Columns button.

Comment: FYI: TAB is default as far as I know

Comment: This is perfect! Essentially this is how we can reset excel back to its original configuration where text to column split would happen only on a tab by default (or else whatever you had set it to before).

Answer (score 3):

I created a quick Macro and added it to my personal.xlsm file. Here is the code. This more or less does the same thing that Leigh Riffel has suggested except it is a quick Macro run.

```
Sub DisableAutoSplitting()
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("C2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Beware: running a macro loses your Undo history.

Answer (score 0):

Or just click into the formula bar or into the cell as if you are typing, then paste - it will then only go into that cell. (LOL creating a macro - so over complicated)

Comment: This works if you're trying to paste into only one cell.  It doesn't work for pasting into multiple rows because all the lines end up in the one cell.